# How in the heck does this colloquial japanese sentence make any sense grammatically?

Tags: grammar, kanji, syntax, kana

I am aware that this is colloquial japanese, but the individual parts are jumbled haphazardly to where I can't figure out how this is supposed to follow even somewhat correct grammar. I got 2 translations from another source, but the structure is what confuses me, I mean, the translations seem to take too many liberties and stretches out the japanese too far.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OgtcZOQ_xj8&t=2m26s

> そうなんですよね。もちろん、あの、世界中からいろんなこう惜しむ反応が出るというのは「DS」・「Wii」はもちろんなんですけれども、その前のやっぱりロールプレイングゲームのマザー2とか
> そういうものの、やっぱり、すごいじゃないか、という岩田さんに対する思いがこういう惜しむ声にもつながっているような気がいたしましたけれどもね、はい。

1st translation I received from the forum of another website:

> Basically it's saying "I attribute the expression of regrets from all over the world to people's thoughts that he's done amazing works including not only DS and Wii, but also an older role playing game Mother 2"

2nd translation:

> That's right. Of course, umm, the condolences from around the world are of course from his work on the DS and the Wii, but also the role playing game Earthbound.I think that the expressions of condolence are connected to how people think how amazing Iwata's work on these things is.

My breakdown of this speech:

> Of course, there are various condolences from all over the world, such as for the "DS" and "Wii", but before that, the previous role-playing game Mother 2 and so on.

そういうもののやっぱり
(google translate)
After all such a thing
After all of those things

すごいじゃないか
amazing!

岩田さんに対する思いがこういう惜しむ声にもつながっているような気がいたしましたけれどもね、はい。
I felt that the condolences are connected to these kinds of fan's memories of Mr. Iwata.

Comment: The both:  "(google translate) After all such a thing After all of those things" are google translation? And, I know it's hard to format Japanese and English properly, but I guess we need a little bit of format needed. For me, it's hard to highlight where your breakdown sentences are (Original Dialogue → 1st →  2nd → your breakdown)

Comment: @kimi Tanaka Thanks for the reply! Those two sentences did result from google translate, yes. To me this speech was confusing because it seems to mix the order of speech in any way. The sentence containing "Earthbound" and before are not difficult, it's after that, そういうもののやっぱりand thereon. Literally the news announcer says, " 'How amazing' 'Iwata's work on these things is how people think' 'I think that the expressions of condolence are connected to'.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't factor という into your breakdown between すごいじゃないか and 岩田さんに対する思い

Comment: Does factoring it in change your understanding of the sentence at all? You seem to feel that that portion is the most confusing, so leaving out a bit could have an effect on how it's read... at least that's what I was thinking.

Comment: @Leebo Thanks for the response. I guess what I'm trying to say is, I find it both amazing and confusing how japanese can be spoken with all the parts jumbled in any seemingly random order and still make sense to them.

Comment: @SomaRise I am also always struggling with it though, I humbly recommend you format like Chocolate-San way. And, move on to the content, I think it's rather formal than colloquial. It's tying to be reserved in manner. They are carefully choosing words, so it may sound haphazard.

Comment: I guess this (parts jumbled) is what happens with verbatim transcriptions. When I speak without a script, it can contain a lot of mess as a written text, but it's hard to notice when you speak or you listen to. Interviews need to be edited to become a proper document; and I'm guessing it's regardless of language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic structure of the sentence is:

> 世界中から惜しむ反応が出るというのは、
> There are condolences from around the world, which means,
> 岩田さんに対する思いが惜しむ声にもつながっている
> Thoughts toward Iwata-san have led to the condolences.
> ような気がいたしました。
> That's what I felt.

So I would parse it this way:

> 世界中からいろんなこう惜しむ反応が出るというのは、
> There are various condolences like this from around the world, which means,
>
> 【「DS」・「Wii」はもちろんなんですけれども、その前のやっぱりロールプレイングゲームのマザー2とかそういうものの、やっぱり、すごいじゃないか、という】岩田さんに対する思いが
> People's thoughts toward Mr. Iwata 【that not only DS and Wii, but also the previous role playing game Mother 2 or such things are, after all, amazing】
>
> こういう惜しむ声にもつながっている
> have led to these condolences.
>
> ような気がいたしました
> That's what I felt.

"「DS」・「Wii」はもちろんなんですけれども、その前のやっぱりロールプレイングゲームのマザー2とかそういうものの、やっぱり、すごいじゃないか" is the content of the 思い.

So I think the 1st translation in your post ("I attribute the expression of regrets from all over the world to people's thoughts that he's done amazing works including not only DS and Wii, but also an older role playing game Mother 2") is good.

Does this make sense to you?

Comment: Thanks to everyone that replied! Any reply is better than none, as I always say. I feel like in english we generally speak in the order of 1,2,3,4,5 and in japanese they can get away with 5,3,2,4,1. (Like, they start off with the last idea of the sentence, then mixed up and so on.)